# When I pass an object to a JavaScript function does that object get passed by reference?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have a function that looks like the function below. It takes an object called 
`link`, calls `getAdminParams` and then uses the return values of that call to 
change properties in the link object:

```
function checkParams(link: Link) {
    var rtn : IAdminParams = null,
        table = null;
    if (link.Action === "Create") {
        if (link.Params == null) {
            rtn = getAdminParams(link.Entity);
            if (rtn.Success) {
                link.Url = link.Href + rtn.Param;
                table = rtn.Table;
            } else {
                link.$Link.prop('disabled', false);
                return;
            }
        } else {
            link.Url = link.Href + link.Params;
            table = link.Entity;
        }
    } else {
        link.Url = link.Href;
    }
}
```

I am calling the function as below.

```
function adminDialog($link: JQuery) {
    var link = new Link($link);
    checkParams(link);
    doDialogAjax(link);
}
```

When I pass the value of link to the `checkParams(link)` will it be passed by 
reference? In other words will the changes I make in the `checkParams(link: Link)` 
function be available to the link object so they can be used in the `doDialogAjax`
function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and no.

> "When I pass the value of link to the checkParams(link) will it be
>   passed by reference?"

No.

> "Will the changes I make in the checkParams(link: Link)
>   function be available to the link object so they can be used in the
>   doDialogAjax function?"

Yes.

The variable is not passed *by* reference. It's passed by value, but the value is a reference.

If the variable was passed by reference, the function could change the variable. That doesn't happen:

```
function change(obj) {
  // change the object
  obj.value = 42;
  // replace it with a new object
  obj = { value: 1 };
}

// create an object
var a = { value: 0 };

// create another variable, to use in the call to the function
var b = a;

change(b);

alert(a.value); // shows 42, as the function changes the object passed in
alert(b.value); // shows 42, not 1, as the variable b is not changed by the function
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sCJHu/

If the variable was passed by reference, `b` would be replaced by the new object create in the function, and `b.value` would be `1`.

Comment: +1 for the line *"The variable is not passed by reference. It's passed by value, but the value is a reference."*, the rest is just gravy. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the changes you make in the function receiving the object are visible in other uses of the objects.

Simple test :

```
​function increment(obj) {
    obj.a++;    
}
var myobj = {a:3};
increment(myobj);
document.write(myobj.a); // prints 4
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/deSsR/)

Answering a comment : arrays are objects and it [works the same](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/crGmH/).

You might see, in this precise case, the passing mode as a *"pass by reference"* but that's just using some vocabulary of another language : you pass the value of the variable and variable values for objects are their references. The problem with this vocabulary is exemplified by Archer's mistake : you can't replace the variable's value :

```
​function increment(obj) {
    obj = {a:4}; // doesn't change the passed object, just the local variable obj
}
var myobj = {a:3};
increment(myobj);
document.write(myobj.a); // prints 3 because myobj isn't changed
```

To say it otherwise : a function can **modify** an object that is the value of an external variable passed to it, it can't **replace** it. Because you don't pass a reference to original variable as you would do in C.

Comment: so sweet little nice demo! +10

Comment: *"You can see it as a "pass by reference"."* ***Please*** don't perpetuate that myth. It's not pass by reference. It's pass by value. The value being passed is an object reference, but just because the word "reference" appears in both terms, it doesn't mean they're the same.

Comment: Doesn't work with arrays - incomplete answer. [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hqNL/)

Comment: @Archer: What do you mean? Sure it does, exactly the way it works with objects (unsurprisingly, as arrays **are** objects). Can you explain your point a bit more?

Comment: @Archer: See my reply to your comment on my answer, I believe you're falling prey to the special behavior of `console.log` on some browsers.

Comment: @Archer : I edited my answer to make it more clear to you. Not that there is nothing specific to array there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - nope it does the same using alerts.  Check my example to see.

Comment: @dystroy Thanks for the clarification.  I *did* think it was just arrays, but it's clearly not.  Perhaps this needs a better explanation as it's clearly not a case of passing variables by reference, or your 2nd example would work.

Comment: @Archer: Right, variables are not passed by reference. I even **say** that in my answer, which someone downvoted at the same time as your comment on it. If it was you, perhaps reconsider. In any case, best to clean up all of these comments, to avoid confusing people. The answers are correct, although I for one really wish dystroy wouldn't say it's anything vaguely like "pass by reference," since (as you point out) it **isn't**. But I commented on that earlier.

Answer (score -1):

> When I pass an object to a javascript function does that object get passed by reference?

A reference to the object is passed to the function (this is *not* "pass by reference", that's a different thing entirely). A simpler example helps make this clear:

```
function foo(o1) {
    console.log("foo1: o1.a = " + o1.a);
    o1.a = "updated";    // <=== MODIFYING the object
    console.log("foo2: o1.a = " + o1.a);
}
function bar(o2) {
    console.log("bar1: o2.a = " + o2.a);
    o2 = {a: "updated"}; // <=== Pointing to a DIFFERENT object (no effect outside function)
    console.log("bar2: o2.a = " + o2.a);
}

var x = {a: "original x"};
foo(x);           // Logs "foo1: o1.a = original x",
                  // then "foo2: o1.a = updated"
console.log(x.a); // Logs "updated"

var y = {a: "original y"};
bar(y);           // Logs "bar1: o2.a = original y",
                  // then "bar2: o2.a = updated"
console.log(y.a); // Logs "original y", *NOT* "updated"
```

Note that this is **pass by value**; the value in question with objects is an object reference. You may see people calling it "pass by reference," but that's fundamentally wrong. If a variable is "pass by reference," that means you can change the variable's value *in the calling code*. E.g., it would mean our functions could change what `x` and `y` refer to. But they can't, as we can see from `bar` above. They can only change properties on the objects that `x` and `y` refer to, not `x` and `y` themselves.